# Django broken pipe error when handling large file

Tags: javascript, django, file

A server developed using the Django framework is hosted in a local environment, and a broken pipe error occurs in the process of processing large files.

The current problem is the code below, which is to respond by changing the DICOM file to the png extension through a separate view to deal with the DICOM file. There is no problem in normal cases, but a broken pipe error occurs when processing about 15MB of files.

```js
# javascript code for request file data in html template

function loadImages(images, fileType, index) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (index < images.length) {
          var image = images[index];
          var fileName = image.image_url.split('/').pop();
          var imageData = {
            fileName: fileName,
          };
      
          imageInfoArray.push(imageData);

          var img = new Image();
          img.onload = function() {
            var filePreviewHTML = `
              <li class="add-image-${index}">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="img-wrap" data-id="${index}">
                  <img src="${(fileName.endsWith('.DCM')) ? '/dicom/' + fileName : image.image_url}" alt="ask-file-img"/>
                  <button class="remove-file" onclick="disableImage('${image.image_url}')"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
                </a>
                <p class="file-name">${fileName}</p>
              </li>
            `;

            var filePreview = $('.file-preview[data-file="' + fileType + '"]');
            filePreview.append(filePreviewHTML);

            loadImages(images, fileType, index + 1);
          }

          img.src = (fileName.endsWith('.DCM')) ? '/dicom/' + fileName : image.image_url;
        }
```

```
// view code for handling DICOM file

def show_dicom(request, file_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "xray_images", file_path)
    dicom = pydicom.dcmread(file_path)

    image_array = apply_voi_lut(dicom.pixel_array, dicom)
    image_array_2d = image_array[0] if len(image_array.shape) > 2 else image_array

    norm = Normalize(vmin=image_array_2d.min(), vmax=image_array_2d.max())
    image_array_2d = norm(image_array_2d)

    plt.imshow(image_array_2d, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
    plt.axis('off')

    buffer = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buffer, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    buffer.seek(0)
    plt.close()

    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
```

when handling the file about 15MB large, the below error is occurred.

```
[20/Oct/2023 14:10:58,643] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50065)
```

Can someone help me please?

I thought that the problem is occurred cause file is too large to send.
so I tried to resize file.

1. Resize file
2. Compress file